# DictVectorizer with a large dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a large dataset with categorical values and tried to encode them using `DictVectorizer`. The following is a snippet of the code I tried.

```
dv = DictVectorizer(sparse=True)
_dicts = []
for line in fp:
    _dict = create_dict_feature(line)
    _dicts.append(_dict)
dv.fit_transform(_dicts)
```

But, `MemoryError` occurs in `_dicts.append(_dict)`. I am wondering what would be an efficient way of getting around this problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, `fit_transform` can take an iterable. If the memory issue is coming from the size of the list, consider using a generator instead of a `list`, which will yield your `dict`s one at a time as it is iterated.

```
_dicts = (create_dict_feature(line) for line in fp)
dv = DictVectorizer(sparse=True)
dv.fit_transform(_dicts)
```

This won't help much if `fit_transform` accumulates the `dict`s or `Mapping`s just as you were doing before.